# Android webview doesn't execute some javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have app with Webview with setting:

```
    wvPage = new WebView(this);
    WebSettings webSettings = wvPage.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wvPage.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wvPage.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient();
```

I loaded some url by using **loadUrl("`http://some.url/`")** and start clicking on some references. Some of clicked references didn't open. I inspect code of this page:

These refs opened normally:

```
<a href="http://some.url">some text</a>
```

These refs didn't open:

```
<a value="http://some.url">some text</a>
```

I tryed to check this issue in default browser in my tab. All works fine. Then I uncheck JS support in setting of the browser. After that default browser began to behave like my webview. So I decided that problem is in JS setting. But my webview executed some JS scenarios before I started clicking on refs and furthermore **getJavaScriptEnabled()** gave me **true** result;

*Are there any other permissions or supersecret settings which I need to turn on/off or whatever else?*